# React select passing props for components to useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use useMemo for the Option custom component in the react select.

When I tried it getting issue, am I missing something in the below code snippet?

*Getting props undefined*

```
const Option = useMemo(
    (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <components.Option {...props}>
            <checkbox checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} />
            <label>{props.label}</Label>
          </components.Option>
        </div>
      );
    },
    [props]
  );




<Select components={{Option}} />
```

Tried this approach but still getting the props undefined

```
<Select components={{Option: (optionProps) => <Option {...optionProps}/>}}
```

Still no luck.

Added a reproducible code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-spence-8hg48)

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Cool @ halfer, thanks for the edit, Getting the props undefined and added already what i have tried but no luck

Comment: In particular, please refrain from flowery notes of appreciation at the end of your questions. You have had a good number removed from your material in the past, and there is an expectation that when you see an edit notification, you take note of the changes that are being made.

Comment: Sure @halfer since getting a help is good, so usually its good isn't to greet for the help and the time he is spending to solve

Comment: The community consensus says "no" to that. Please read [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776) and [Being polite while asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266525) and several other questions on Meta. Succinct, technical writing is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Option = useMemo(
    () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <components.Option {...props}>
            <checkbox checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} />
            <label>{props.label}</Label>
          </components.Option>
        </div>
      );
    },
    [props]
  );
```

No need to pass any arguments to `useMemo()` callback.

Try changing `(props) =>` to `() =>` in `useMemo` callback.

For your [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);
```

update `CustomSelect.js` as below

```js
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const CustomSelect = props => {
const Option = useMemo(() => {
  return (
    <div>
      <components.Option {...props}>
        <checkbox checked={props.isSelected} onChange={() => null} />
        <label>{props.label}</label>
      </components.Option>
    </div>
  );
}, [props]);

const MultiValue = useMemo(() => {
  return (
    <components.MultiValue {...props}>
      <span>{props.label}</span>
    </components.MultiValue>
  );
}, [props]);

  return <Select options={options} isMulti components={(Option, MultiValue)} />
};

export default CustomSelect;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Nope this didn't worked @prathap

Comment: Kindly check this, i have reproduced the issue here https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-spence-8hg48

Comment: Cool. Thanks for reproducing the issue.

Comment: Let me know if you know how to do this, i didn't find much reference on using this hook

Comment: Will update the answer (CustomSelect.js) file. And remember one thing `The thumb rule of hooks is you should only use hooks inside react component` not outside of it.

Comment: So you are suggesting that we should not use useMemo in this scenario

Comment: We can use any hook according to your requirement. I have just moved them inside `CustomSelect` component. Remember the thumb rule `Always use hooks inside React component`. Better if you add eslint plugin for `react hooks` and enforce lint rules. That would help you to use hooks correctly.

Comment: If `props` is working fine and you are not getting desired results then it's time to look at `react-select` docs for custom component rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217679/discussion-between-prathap-reddy-and-dileep-thomas).